# Pandoc: Latex to Html file conversion ignore address, affiliation and other tag

Tags: latex, pandoc

When I try to convert latex to HTML using pandoc, HTML file is created but the address, affiliation, and some other tags are missing in HTML.

The following tags are missing

1. \address
2. \affiliation
3. \ead

I tried to write all pandoc AST data in file and find missing tags using pandoc Python filter, but no data exists for the above tags

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str

def writeToFile(key, value, format, meta):
    with open("example.txt", "a") as file:
        # Write data to the file
        file.write(key)
        file.write(" ")
        json.dump(value, file)
        file.write(" ")
        json.dump(format, file)
        file.write(" ")
        json.dump(meta, file)
        file.write("\n")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(writeToFile)
```

any way in pandoc to parse ignore tags and include them in converted HTML file?